# iOS 13 Location permission - What is the behaviour after upgrading from iOS 12

Tags: swift, core-location, ios13

Is the new iOS 13 location permission change affects previous iOS versions upgrade? Or it is applied only for new application installations on iOS 13?

I request for `requestAlwaysAuthorization` in iOS 12 and the user selects always.

Now the user update to iOS 13.

Will the Always status change to provisional mode, or it will stay in "constant" mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since I didn't find a complete answer for this, I decided to test it by myself "The hard way".

It seems like the new permission system only affects fresh install of apps, rather than existing apps.

What I did in order to test it is:

- Roll back to iOS 12 (12.4 was the latest stable)
- Remove my application
- Reset the location & privacy in settings
- Install and launch my application
- Request for location permission using `requestAlwaysAuthorization` and select **Always**
- Install iOS 13 (actually iOS 13.1 which is the latest as for now)
- After installation completed, I went straight to my application permission page and saw that the permission is still on "Always".

I hope it helps anyone